# 16.04.2, linux-image-4.8 & nvidia 367

Tags: nvidia, kernel, nvidia-optimus

I have a Thinkpad P50, with optimus graphics. Under 16.04.1 generic kernel, Optimus works well (I have 3 screens working in XFCE).

Knowing that 16.04.2 is around the corner with a kernel upgrade, I saw that there are already linux-image-4.8 kernels in my repositories. e.g. 4.8.0-32.generic

When I install that, the nvidia driver doesn't load. I am using the standard driver, 367.57-0ubuntu0

I am concerned that it won't work with 16.04.2 
Should I report a bug somewhere, or should I just wait?

Comment: I wouldn't bother reporting a bug, simply use the supported kernel which works.

Comment: Yakkety (16.10), which is already using kernel 4.8.0-32.generic is also using 367.57-0ubuntu3. So perhaps 16.04.2 will also.

Comment: There is no updated Nvidia driver in the proposed repository, and unless this is fixed, 16.04.2 will break nvidia systems (at least, it will break mine). However, it should be easy to fix since 16.10 does work (and see my answer: the 375 driver in the graphics-drivers PPA works too)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked: use the drivers PPA and install v 375. I did it from the command line.

```
tim@raffles:/ uname -r
4.8.0-32-generic


sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt purge nvidia*
sudo apt install nvidia-375
```

(via https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa )